# Pandas merging two dataframes with different number of multiindices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Welcome, I have a simple question, to which I haven't found a solution.

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`:

- `df1` contains several columns and a multiindex as `year-month-week`
- `df2` contains the multiindex `year-week` with only one column in the df.

---

I would like to create an `inner join` of `df1` and `df2`, joining on `'year'` and `'week'`.

---

I have tried to do the following:

```
df1['newcol'] = df1.index.get_level_values(2).map(lambda x: df2.newcol[x])
```

Which only joins on month (or year?), is there any way to expand it so that the merge is actually right?

Thanks in advance!

[df1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CLBz.png)

[df2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgT9a.png)

Comment: Can you provide a sample dataframe via a **[mcve]**.

Comment: Show us some sample of the datasets. Refer to the guide on how to add code snippets.

Comment: I added some pictures to represent the dataset, i hope it helps!

Comment: We can't copy/paste pictures into python :D

Comment: Did you try `pd.merge([df1, df2], how = 'inner', on = ['year', 'week']`?

Comment: for pd.merge i get the following error: 
You are trying to merge on int64 and object columns.
Is there anyway to cast here?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually i solved with with removing the multiindex and doing a good old inner join on the two columns and then recreating the multiindex at the end. 
Here are the sniplets:

df=df.reset_index()

df2=df2.reset_index()

df['year']=df['year'].apply(int)

df2['year']=df2['year'].apply(int)

df['week']=df['week'].apply(int)

df2['week']=df2['week'].apply(int)

result = pd.merge(df, df2,  how='left', left_on=                                                             ['year','week'],right_on= ['year','week'])

result=result.set_index(['year', 'month','week','day'])

Comment: Since flattening index is not that intuitive for many, I'd suggest that you could add the actual code that you used, so that others could benefit from your experience ;) https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/